# Make a timeout if the host didn't response during the 2-3 second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I want to check if a web host is available so i used the code down below, it works, but sometimes if the site is slow in response it keep waiting, how do i implant a timeout into it? if no response from the host withen 2-3 second, return false also. Please help me out

```
- (BOOL)isDataSourceAvailable {

    static BOOL checkNetwork = YES;
    static BOOL _isDataSourceAvailable = NO;
    if (checkNetwork) { // Since checking the reachability of a host can be expensive, cache the result and perform the reachability check once.
        checkNetwork = NO;
        Boolean success;
        const char *host_name = "google.com"; //HOST
        SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, host_name);
        SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
        success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
        _isDataSourceAvailable = success && (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable) && !(flags & kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired);
        CFRelease(reachability);
    }
    return _isDataSourceAvailable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple

Just implement `NSTimer`

Example

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

if targetMethod: is called, then its timeout.

Here don't forget to call

```
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil;
```

if you receive response from server.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The code i'm using is  blocking my app... how can that be fixed? i used thread, but it keep frizzing until it done loading

Comment: This above code will block your application for 2 seconds only

Comment: if needed you can use performSelectorInBackground: function

Comment: can you show any example? what is myTimer? what is it declared to? connect to

Comment: Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Comment: Thanks!! just what i need to know

Comment: @Prateek Unfortunately since the OP appears to be using `SCNetworkReachability*` in blocking mode a timer will not help (i.e. the code will never return into the event loop, will never see the timer and will continue blocking).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `SCNetworkReachability*` calls in blocking mode. You need to set a callback using `SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback` and then schedule it in the run loop `SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop`. You can find further information at [Apple's Reachability Example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6). When you use callbacks you can use an `NSTimer` (similar to what user Prateek describes) to abort the current reachability task.

You will have to modify you code because instead of making a function/method call and immediately knowing the answer you will make a function/method call and wait for one of three callbacks: reachability success, reachability failure or timeout.

Comment: @user1480092 I've named most of the calls you will need to use and given you a link to an Apple example that shows you how to do non-blocking calls. To see an example of non-blocking use please click on the on the "Apple's Reachability Example" in my answer above.